# Browser will prompt a download local PHP files rather than displaying the HTML/CSS content

Tags: php, html, css, browser

Working on a Mac with the latest software update. I've tried opening the PHP files in multiple browsers, each time it prompts me for a download.

I understand I could create a local server to actually run the scripts but I'm currently just editing the CSS on each page. I was using Firefox to track my CSS edits but all of a sudden it began doing this.

My apologies if I'm being vague, also I've researched the issue but I've mainly been finding the solution is to create a local server.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built-in web server. If you don't want to install local server, you may use it for testing:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

*Take note that you can never test PHP scripts without a server.*

If you don't have PHP installed in your local, download it [here](http://php.net/downloads.php).

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP script are simple and you don't need web server features like url rewriting you can use build-in web server in php (which is installed on mac by default).

1. First open a Terminal.app
2. Navigate to folder with your files
3. Start web server using command: `php -S localhost:port` ex. `php -S localhost:8000`
4. Navigate to file in your web browser for example to file `sample.php` enter: `http://localhost:8000/sample.php`

---

You can find more about build-in PHP web server here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. I ended up using this method.

Comment: No problem, @Andrew :) You can also vote up for my answer for others :)